# Probability Distribution Function - Question

Tags: probability

Q: If X ~ N (3,3) and Y ~ N (-0.5,0.25) are independent, find the probability that W = X + 2Y is negative

I took it as a Normal Distribution

W~N(3-2(0.5),3+2(0.25)) = (2,3.5)

z = (0-2)/Sqrt(3.5) = -1.069

Pr(z<-1.069) = 0.5 - 0.3577 = **0.1423**

Can someone advise me if 0.1423 is the correct Pr for the Question and if my reasoning is correct?

Comment: It's not clear exactly what probability you are trying to calculate. Also you need to use $$Var(W)=Var(X)+2^2Var(Y)$$

Comment: sorry edited the question, it was meant to read the probability that W=X+2Y is **negative**

Comment: $var(\alpha X + \beta Y) = \alpha^2 var(X) + \beta^2 var(Y)$

Answer (score 1):

The correct answer is obtained by computing $ z= \frac{0 - 2}{\sqrt{4}}$ and not $\sqrt{3.5}$. This is so because the variance of $W$ is $ 3 + 2^2 *0.25$ according to $var(\alpha X + \beta Y) = \alpha^2 var(X) + \beta^2 var(Y)$

Comment: from there for i find Pr(Z=-1) = 0.5 - 0.3413 right? thansk for you responses!